# Priority queue in C for operating system

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, priority-queue

I need to write a new function called enqueue_priority using my previous enqueue and dequeue functions I cant use sort premade sort I dont know how to implement the priority queue. This is for a simple linux operating system. I am just dragging this out because stack says that My question is mostly code and needs more words but I dont have anything else to say about it
this struct is in a different file

```
struct pcb {
    uint32_t esp;
    uint32_t pid;
    struct pcb *next;
    uint32_t priority;
};
typedef struct pcb pcb_t;
#endif
```

starts new file

```
struct pcbq {
    pcb_t *head;
    pcb_t *tail;   
};
typedef struct pcbq pcbq_t;

pcbq_t RR_q;
pcb_t *Running;

void initq(pcbq_t *q) {
    q->head = q->tail = 0;
}

bool comparePTR(pcb_t *a1, pcb_t *a2) {
    return a1->priority < a2->priority;
}

    
void enqueue_priority (pcbq_t *q, pcb_t *item){
    // item->next = 0;  
    // if (q->tail == 0) {
    //     q->tail = q->head = item;
    // } else {
    //     q->tail->next = item;
    //     q->tail = item;
    // }

}

void enqueue(pcbq_t *q, pcb_t *item) {
    item->next = 0;  
    if (q->tail == 0) {
        q->tail = q->head = item;
    } else {
        q->tail->next = item;
        q->tail = item;
    }
}

void default_handler();
pcb_t *dequeue(pcbq_t *q) {
    if (q->head == 0) {
        default_handler();
    }
    pcb_t *item = q->head;
    q->head = q->head->next;
    return item;
}

void init_rrq() {
    Running = 0;
    initq(&RR_q);
}

// returns 1 if no process is on the ready Q
int rr_schedule() {
    if (Running == 0) {
        default_handler();
    }
    if (RR_q.head == 0)
        return 1;    // running process is the only one in the system
    enqueue(&RR_q, Running);
    Running = dequeue(&RR_q);
    return 0;
}

void rr_schedule_first() {
    if (RR_q.head == 0)
        default_handler();
    Running = dequeue(&RR_q);
}

void rr_enqueue(pcb_t *pcb) {
    enqueue(&RR_q, pcb);
}
```

Comment: *"I dont know how to implement the priority queue."* - Honestly, don't use a queue to do it; use a binary-heap. But yes, you can use a regular queue, so long as you don't mind the O(N^2) worst case complexity.

Comment: A queue is required

Comment: @WhozCraig Inserting s new item to a sorted queue is only O(N), which is the meaningful metric, since items also get removed from the queue. If all items are inserted at once, then it's a case of sorting, which is O(n log n).

Comment: @colegreen "priority queue" means something where you can push items, and when you pop them, they come out in priority order. This has little to do with a FIFO type 
"normal" queue. Heap is the go-to data structure for a serious priority queue implementation.

Comment: Often, in OS kernels, a restricted range of priorities is all that is required.  In those cases, an array[priority] of queues is a good choice - you do not need to sort, insertion is trivial and removal requires searching the array for the highest-priority queue that is not empty:)

Comment: “I don’t know how to implement the priority queue.” You should check out http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Priority_queue#C

Answer (score 2):

*Note:* As others have mentioned, there are better ways to implement a priority queue. But ...

To implement a priority queue with a linked list, one way is to insert the new item in the correct sorted place when we add a new item.

We have to scan the list looking for the proper place.

Your code had elements of both a *doubly* linked list and *singly* linked list. But, it was *mostly* a singly linked list (e.g. your `pcb` didn't have a `prev` pointer).

The only time the `tail` was used, was to append to the back of the list (in `enqueue`).

But, to maintain the sort, we'd probably never want to use that, but, only `enqueue_priority`.

So, I've simplified the code. Also, the `RR*` stuff wasn't relevant to the queue insertion, so I've elided that as well.

I've coded this, but *not* tested it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct pcb {
    uint32_t esp;
    uint32_t pid;
    uint32_t priority;
    struct pcb *next;
};
typedef struct pcb pcb_t;

struct pcbq {
    pcb_t *head;
};
typedef struct pcbq pcbq_t;

void
initq(pcbq_t *q)
{
    q->head = NULL;
}

// enqueue_priority -- enqueue item in proper sorted order
void
enqueue_priority(pcbq_t *q, pcb_t *item)
{
    pcb_t *bef = NULL;
    pcb_t *cur = q->head;

    item->next = NULL;

    // find the lower priority (use rightmost of same/equal priority)
    for (;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next) {
        if (cur->priority > item->priority)
            break;
        bef = cur;
    }

    do {
        // empty queue
        if (q->head == NULL) {
            q->head = item;
            break;
        }

        // insert after lower
        if (bef != NULL) {
            item->next = bef->next;
            bef->next = item;
        }

        // insert before head of non-empty queue
        else {
            item->next = q->head;
            q->head = item;
        }
    } while (0);
}

// enqueue -- enqueue at back of queue
void
enqueue(pcbq_t *q, pcb_t *item)
{
    pcb_t *cur = q->head;
    pcb_t *bef = NULL;

    item->next = NULL;

    for (;  cur != NULL;  cur = cur->next)
        bef = cur;

    // append to end of queue
    if (bef != NULL)
        bef->next = item;

    // empty list
    else
        q->head = item;
}

// dequeue -- dequeue from front of queue
pcb_t *
dequeue(pcbq_t *q)
{
    pcb_t *item = q->head;

    do {
        if (item == NULL)
            break;

        q->head = item->next;

        item->next = NULL;
    } while (0);

    return item;
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

The above requires a list scan. However, if we used *separate* queues for each priority level, we could use a modified version of the above to enqueue and dequeue faster (we add back the `tail` pointer).

This is [AFAIK] how OSes actually do it. It requires that we look at each queue and check for a non-null `head`, but with few(er) priority levels (e.g. 10), this will be faster when we have (e.g.) thousands of processes.

So, here's the modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct pcb {
    uint32_t esp;
    uint32_t pid;
    uint32_t priority;
    struct pcb *next;
};
typedef struct pcb pcb_t;

struct pcbq {
    pcb_t *head;
    pcb_t *tail;
};
typedef struct pcbq pcbq_t;

#define MAXPRIORITY     10
pcbq_t allqueues[MAXPRIORITY];

void
initq(pcbq_t *q)
{
    q->head = NULL;
}

// enqueue -- enqueue at back of queue
void
enqueue(pcbq_t *q, pcb_t *item)
{

    item->next = NULL;

    // empty list
    if (q->tail == NULL) {
        q->tail = item;
        q->head = item;
    }

    // append to end of queue
    else {
        q->tail->next = item;
        q->tail = item;
    }
}

// enqueue_priority -- enqueue item in proper sorted order
void
enqueue_priority(pcbq_t *q, pcb_t *item)
{

    q += item->priority;
    enqueue(q,item);
}

// dequeue -- dequeue from front of queue
pcb_t *
dequeue(pcbq_t *q)
{
    pcb_t *item = q->head;

    do {
        if (item == NULL)
            break;

        q->head = item->next;

        if (item == q->tail)
            q->tail = NULL;
    } while (0);

    return item;
}

// dequeue_priority -- dequeue from front of highest priority queue
pcb_t *
dequeue_priority(pcbq_t *q)
{
    pcb_t *item = NULL;

    for (int qidx = 0;  qidx < MAXPRIORITY;  ++qidx, ++q) {
        if (q->head != NULL) {
            item = dequeue(q);
            break;
        }
    }

    return item;
}
```